# Simplification of an expression.

Tags: gamma-function, products, algebra-precalculus

I've been working on analysing one system lately, I arrived to an expression which I'd like to simplify more, still couldn't manage to.

I arrived to the following expression :
$\sum_{k = n+2}^{N+1}\gamma^k\prod_{t=n+2}^{k}(1-(t-n-1)\alpha); n \in N , \alpha \in R$, and $\gamma<1$.

I just included the sum operator for illustration.

What I'd like to know, if there's a way to write :

$\prod_{t=n+2}^{k}(1-(t-n-1)\alpha)$

in a more simplified way. I was thinking about the Gamma function, since this expression looks like a combination of factorials somehow to me, but didn't manage to figure out how can I arrive there.

Thank you

Comment: This might be helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials  But you're almost certainly going to have to do something involving binomial coefficients due to the two terms in use.

Comment: Maybe rewriting as $$\prod_{t=n+1}^{k-1}(1-(t-n-1)\alpha) = \prod_{t=1}^{k-n-2}(1-\alpha t)$$ gives you something...

Comment: With CAS: $$\sum _{k=n+2}^{N+1} \gamma ^k \prod _{t=n+2}^k (1-(t-n-1) \alpha )=e^{\frac{1}{\alpha  \gamma }} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha  \gamma }\right)^{-1/\alpha } \left(-\frac{(-1+\alpha ) \gamma ^n \Gamma
   \left(-1+\frac{1}{\alpha },\frac{1}{\alpha  \gamma }\right)}{\alpha ^2}-\frac{(-\alpha )^{-n+N} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha  \gamma }\right)^{-n+N} \gamma ^N \Gamma \left(2-n+N-\frac{1}{\alpha }\right) \Gamma
   \left(-1+n-N+\frac{1}{\alpha },\frac{1}{\alpha  \gamma }\right)}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can employ the Gamma function to get a convenient representation.

> We obtain for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{t=n+2}^{k}}&\color{blue}{\left(1-\left(t-n-1\right)\alpha\right)}\\
> &=\prod_{t=1}^{k-n-1}\left(1-t\alpha\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\alpha^{k-n-1}\prod_{t=1}^{k-n-1}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-t\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\alpha^{k-n-1}\binom{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}{k-n-1}(k-n-1)!\tag{3}\\
> &=\alpha^{k-n-1}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-k+n+1\right)\Gamma(k-n)}(k-n-1)!\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\alpha^{k-n-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-k+n+1\right)}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index by $n+1$ to start with $t=1$.
- In (2) we factor out $\alpha^{k-n-1}$.
- In (3) we use the definition of binomial coefficients for $\beta \in \mathbb{C}, q\in \mathbb{N}$
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{\beta}{q}=\frac{\beta(\beta-1)\cdots(\beta-q+1)}{q!}
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we use the identity $\binom{\beta}{q}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\beta+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\beta - q + 1\right)\Gamma\left(q+1\right)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left. \sum_{k\ =\ n + 2}^{N + 1}\gamma^{k}
\prod_{t\ =\ n + 2}^{k}\bracks{1 -\pars{t - n - 1}\alpha}
\,\right\vert_{{\Large\ n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}} \atop
{{\Large\ \alpha\ \in\ \mathbb{R}} \atop{\Large\ \gamma\ <\ 1}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k\ =\ n + 2}^{N + 1}\gamma^{k}\,\pars{-1}^{k - n - 1}\,
\alpha^{k - n - 1}
\prod_{t\ =\ n + 2}^{k}\pars{t - n - 1 - {1 \over \alpha}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-\alpha}^{-n - 1}\sum_{k\ =\ n + 2}^{N + 1}\pars{-\alpha\gamma}^{k}
\pars{1 - {1 \over \alpha}}^{\overline{k - n - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-\alpha}^{-n - 1}\sum_{k\ =\ n + 2}^{N + 1}\pars{-\alpha\gamma}^{k}\,
{\Gamma\pars{k - n - 1/\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - 1/\alpha}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over \pars{-\alpha}^{n + 1}\,\Gamma\pars{1 - 1/\alpha}}\,\,
\sum_{k\ =\ n + 2}^{N + 1}\pars{-\alpha\gamma}^{k}\,
\pars{k - n - 1 - {1 \over \alpha}}!} \\ &
\end{align}